# How to move internal package / custom made package in R on local machine to R Studio Server Pro

Tags: r, r-package, rstudio-server, fileshare

I recently moved to R and I have to solve an issue where I need to move a customized R package from one server to another server which is Rstudio Pro.

Is there any file share method which could help, Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you go to your RStudio Server Pro instance, can you upload local files with the "Import" button in the "Files" pane?

Comment: @Nate It shows Import dataset from text, sas, spss, strata

Comment: Sorry I think the button is called "Upload". See this pic https://imgur.com/a/S2FJlkS